# Deleting Windows XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-xp-mode

Awhile back I asked a question if I could clone my Windows XP Mode on Windows 7 so I could run it in vmware workstation 8 and I was able to do it by using the vm cloning software and adding the line **xpmode.enabled = "TRUE"** to the .vmx file. (Orig question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/462385/importing-windows-xp-mode-into-vmware-workstation))

I've since been running with a copy in vmware without incident and have been very happy.

I want to recover the space taken up by windows xp mode that was being used through the windows solution and virtual pc.

Can I just delete those vhd's / associated files or is there some dependency I created by using the xpmode.enabled = "TRUE" line.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Just delete the virtual machines if you no longer what a Windows XP virtual machine.  You already created a copy.  If you want you should create another copy just incase something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be clear to delete the .vhd and associated files, as well as uninstall Virtual PC.  After you have successfully cloned it from Virtual PC to VMWare, there are no more dependencies to Virtual PC.